# how to activate mutualSSL on keycloak with Wildfly 26

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I want to activate mutual SSL for keycloak. Within the keycloak admin guide [https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_enable-mtls-wildfly] I found, that  I have add the following to standalone.xml

```
<security-realms>
    <security-realm name="ssl-realm">
        <server-identities>
            <ssl>
                <keystore path="servercert.jks"
                          relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"
                          keystore-password="servercert password"/>
            </ssl>
        </server-identities>
        <authentication>
            <truststore path="truststore.jks"
                        relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"
                        keystore-password="truststore password"/>
        </authentication>
    </security-realm>
</security-realms>
```

but I do not know where.
I have tried to integrate it into the security realms below subsystem=elytron, but I got:

```
| > Message: WFLYCTL0377: Unexpected element
| >   '{urn:wildfly:elytron:15.0}security-realm' encountered. Valid elements
| >   are: 'custom-modifiable-realm, aggregate-realm, failover-realm,
| >   ldap-realm, token-realm, filesystem-realm, custom-realm,
| >   identity-realm, caching-realm, properties-realm, key-store-realm,
| >   distributed-realm, jdbc-realm, jaas-realm'
```

Answer (score 0):

This has changed in Wildfly 25. See [this blog post](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/10/05/WildFly25-Final-Released/#security-layer-changes) for details.

This change is also mentioned in Keycloak's [upgrade guide for version 16.0.0](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/#wildfly-25-upgrade) which is based on Wildfly 25. You will need to configure the Elytron subsystem. Please refer to the [Wildfly documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/25/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#enable-two-way-ssltls-in-wildfly-for-applications) for details.